# Passing many parameters to constructors of all components using Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

Sorry if the question is incorrect, I'm a junior.

I have the following code:

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1(DateTime.Today,
                       "123",
                       0,
                       new Class2("01001", @"E:\ATMSZ\Reg\BASE\REG2019.GDB", DateTime.Now, true) 
);
c1.Work();
```

How do I make it using Autofac?

Without passing the arguments, I got this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Class2>().As<IClass2>(); 
var container = builder.Build();

var component = container.Resolve<Class1>();
component.Work();
```

Comment: Check this out https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html

Comment: Where does these parameters come from ? do you know them when you register classes or at runtime ?Are you sure these parameters are relevant on the constructor on are not related to the `Work` method ?

Comment: @Cyril Durand
1) Transmitted from the shell in which the subroutine, whose code I wrote in the question.
2) I know during registration.
3) Yes, I'm sure!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WithParameter` method to provide parameter during registration.

```
builder.RegisterType<Class1>()
       .As<IClass1>()
       .WithParameter("date", DateTime.Today)
       .WithParameter("i", "123")
       .WithParameter(
           new ResolvedParameter(
               (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(Class2) && pi.Name == "class2",
               (pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<IClass2>()));
```

or register them using lambda

```
builder.Register(ctx => new Class1(DateTime.Today, ..., ctx.Resolve<Class2>())
       .As<IClass1>();
```